# How to communicate nucleo-f429(socket.io- client) with python(socket.io-server)?

Tags: socket.io, server, client, stm32, flask-socketio

I want to communicate between stm32f4 ,which will work as a socket.io client with Python , which will work as a socket.io server.

Comment: The socket.io that is written in javascript?

Comment: I want to make a client  in stm32 nucleo in c language . I know how to make a server in python . i want help in stm32 side which should be work via socket io medium.